# Why does npm start of react say it cannot find

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, create-react-app

Want to open the localhost of react, but after entering `npm start`, the terminal says that it cannot find `sh: env-cmd: command not found`, but I can see it in JSON, everything is normal, and it has not been deleted. I can't find the problem. , so post this question and ask for help, thank you guys [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0qrvM.png)      [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5HBZ.png) These two photos are screenshots of terminal and JSON thank you guys！(I use create react app to make this project,my operating system is Mac os,my editor is VScode)

I hope `npm start` can work smoothly, and open localhost

Comment: Thank you ! I will pay attention when I ask questions later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure `env-cmd` is installed in your machine :

```
npm install -g env-cmd
```

or at least in your project:

```
npm install env-cmd
```

Then close your terminal and restart it, if the issue still occurs try to update your node version